# how do I do helmert encoding in R?

Tags: r, encoding, analytics, xgboost

How do I do Helmert encoding in R?

```
x<-read.csv('filename.csv',header=TRUE, sep=',')
nlevel<-nlevels(x$y)
contr.helmert(nlevel)
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
2    1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
3    0    2   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
4    0    0    3   -1   -1   -1   -1
5    0    0    0    4   -1   -1   -1
6    0    0    0    0    5   -1   -1
7    0    0    0    0    0    6   -1
8    0    0    0    0    0    0    7
```

This is the output I got since the number of levels was 8. I want it in the form of columns. How do I do it?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB3ww.jpg)

Comment: "in the form of columns" -- you can transpose the matrix? Otherwise please provide expected output

Comment: added the image of the expected output

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411134/how-to-calculate-helmert-coding